# Hikari: background animation

Tags: c++, flash, ogre3d, ogre

i have an OGre3D+Hikari application, and i'd like to use a flash animation in a loop in its background.

I've tried to tweak some parameters in createFlashOverlay (specifically the zorder and the tier), but nothing changed: my overlay is still on top of my 3d ogre mesh and i want it to be always in the background.
What could i do?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to composite render buffer contents with Flash stuff in ram like this. An alternative could be *somehow* rendering the Flash content to a texture (every frame) and rendering the texture as a full-screen quad before any other content, with z-writing disabled. The reverse is to get the render buffer contents from video memory every frame and overlay it on top of your Flash app, but that's *even less* elegant... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that Hikari doesn't seem to support Render To Texture (I found no clues of it being able to do that when I searched for it).

If you just want the animation I would recommend [Berkelium](http://www.berkelium.org)

Berkelium is a full-blown browser (Chromium) so it's quite heavy for a gui. Render To Texture does work with it, however.

Just let it render to a texture and use that texture on a mesh in the background.

[Berkelium in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUdrflSOe_Q)